# Nested autowired field stays null in JUNIT test

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have a factory pattern implemented and wanted to test this. Except the fields in this factory method are not getting autowired. It seems like the @Autowired attribute in the factory class is staying null. **I can't use @SpringBootTest annotation because of the blockchain configuration file that gets loaded then**

Below is the code of the service factory, the parserfactory gets autowired correctly in the test. The problems is with the autowired fields of the parserfactory

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ParserFactory {

    @Autowired
    OsirisParser osirisParser;

    public Parser getParser(String system) {
        if (system == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("Progress")) {
            return ProgressCreateService();
        }
        if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("Osiris")) {
            log.debug("Osiris parsen creëren");
            return OsirisCreateService();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public OsirisParser OsirisCreateService() {
        return osirisParser;
    }

    public OsirisParser ProgressCreateService() {
        return new OsirisParser("ProgressParser");
    }
```

**The test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class FactoryTest {

    @Mock
    ParserFactory serviceCallFactory;

    @Test
    public void testCreateOsirisServiceSuccesFull() {
        Parser serv = serviceCallFactory.getParser("Osiris");
        assertThat(serv, instanceOf(OsirisParser.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateProgressServiceSuccesFull()  {
        Parser serv = serviceCallFactory.getParser("Progress");
        assertThat(serv, instanceOf(ProgressParser.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateProgressServiceUnSuccessFull() {
        Parser serv = serviceCallFactory.getParser("Progrddess");
        assertThat(serv, is(not(instanceOf(OsirisParser.class))));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateWhenStringIsNotCorrect() {
        Parser serv = serviceCallFactory.getParser("0$iri$");
        assertThat(serv, is(nullValue()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateWhenStringIsNull() {
        Parser serv = serviceCallFactory.getParser("");
        assertThat(serv,  is(nullValue()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any spring context in your test class, which means that you are testing a POJO with no spring initialization to it, so the autowiring does not happen and the field is null.

There are several ways to solve it:

- If you want to test it like a POJO, set the field on the tested class. you can use `@InjectMocks`, `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` in your current implementation, or move the `@Autowire` to a constructor or setter and create the class in the test with the field. I vote for autowiring on a constructor
- If you want it to be tested as a spring component, define a `@TestConfiguration` and in there either import your real configuration and override the beans you don't want to be used, or use a completely different spring configuration for the test.

either way works, choose the one that suits you more